# Area under the curve $y=2x^4-x^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Find the area between the curve $y=2x^4-x^2$, the x-axis and the ordinates of the two minima of the curve.

$y=2x^4-x^2=x^2(2x^2-1)\implies$ function is zero at $0,\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

$y'=8x^3-2x\implies$ critical points are $0,\pm\frac12$. We also note that local minima are at $\pm\frac12$ and local maxima at $0$. At, $x=\pm\frac12$, $y=-\frac18$ i.e. ordinate of the minima is $-\frac18$.

So, the graph is similar (**not same**) to the following:

[image]

So, in my opinion, answer should be $2\int_{\frac1{\sqrt2}}^0(2x^4-x^2)dx$. But the answer is given as $2\int_{\frac1{2}}^0(2x^4-x^2)dx$. Looks like they are considering ordinates as $x=\pm\frac12$ but isn't the ordinate $y=-\frac18$?

Comment: The question is a bit strangely written, but I think what it's getting at is this. The term "ordinate" can mean $x$-coordinate or $y$-coordinate. Here, you are integrating with respect to $x$, so both your limits have to be $x$-coordinates. Thus you use the $x$-coordinate of the minimum point, which is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Prasiortle I thought $x$-coordinate was abscissa and $y$-coordinate ordinate.

Comment: That's one usage but another common usage is to use "ordinate" for both co-*ordinates*. So some authors use e.g. "$x$-ordinate" and "$y$-ordinate" as well.

Comment: @Prasiortle ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, the question is a bit vague

Well, if I understand the question correctly I think that they want to find:

[image]

This is also shown in a bigger picture:

[image]

And that blue area is given by:

$$\left|\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}\space\text{d}x\right|-\left|\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}\left(2x^4-x^2\right)\space\text{d}x\right|=\frac{1}{15}\tag1$$